# Does anyone know if there's a way to get a single page for all Google Cloud SDK Docs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm wondering if there exists or if there's a way to get all of the Google Cloud Platform REST API Documentation in a single page?

Take for example this page https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets#Dataset

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to get all the information not just for the "Dataset" endpoint but for all the BigQuery endpoints in a single html document instead of having them in a site like this; the logical conclusion would then be having a single page for all the endpoints BigQuery, Storage, Compute etc etc.

My goal is to download the information so I can reference them offline (and faster)

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this isn't *html* but it does output data which is kinda like a workaround

If one hits `https://discovery.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis` and parses that output, they'll see a bunch of urls for each api. Using BigQuery as an example extracting the data into "a single page" would look like this

```bash
curl https://discovery.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis\
 | jq -r '.items[]|select(.name == "bigquery")|.discoveryRestUrl'\
 | xargs curl
```

This is what I'm doing now in lieu of an html page.